# SearchDelegate, how to open/start a StatelessWidget from buildResults?

Tags: flutter, dart, search

I'm quite new in programming. I have watched/read quite a lot of videos about SearchDelegate on YT and blogs but I don't understand how to get into the buildResult that it opens existing statelessWidgets.

Here is my SearchDelegate as it is now:

```html
class Search extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  final allSearch = [
    "Humpback Whale",
    "Fin Whale",
    "Blue Whale",
  ];

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: () {
            query = "";
          })
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(query),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? allSearch
        : allSearch.where((p) => p.contains(query)).toList();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          showResults(context);
        },
        leading: Icon(Icons.search_rounded),
        title: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
                text: suggestionList[index].substring(0, query.length),
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                children: [
              TextSpan(
                  text: suggestionList[index].substring(query.length),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
            ])),
      ),
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
    );
```

These three "Humpback Whale", "Fin Whale", and "Blue Whale" are just examples what to search for. I was hoping that if you search for Humpback Whale and press on the result:

[Search of "Humpback Whale"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4OYC.png)

to be directed to this page I already created:

[Humpback Whale page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf44j.png)

The route is already set up for all the animals I want e.g.
'/texthumpbackwhale': (context) => TextHumpbackWhale().

Thank you for any kind of help.

UPDATE
here my solution that I figured out now:

I have added this to build results

```html
return ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, listitem.route);
```

```
enter code here
```

and attached in a list of all my pages a string with the route.
All in all the build Results looks like this:

```html
  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? loadAllAnimals()
        : loadAllAnimals()
            .where((p) => p.title.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
            .toList();

    return suggestionList.isEmpty
        ? Text(
            "No Results Found...",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          )
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: suggestionList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final AllAnimals listitem = suggestionList[index];
              return ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, listitem.route);
                },
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      listitem.title,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      listitem.type,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    Divider()
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
  }
```

and my List like this:

```html
class AllAnimals {
  const AllAnimals(this.title, this.type, this.route);
  final String title;
  final String type;
  final String route;
}

List<AllAnimals> loadAllAnimals() {
  var fi = <AllAnimals>[
    AllAnimals("Atlantic Puffin", "Auks", '/atlanticpuffin'),
    //and the other items
   ];
   return fi;
}
```